# C# oracleのデータベースからカラムの型を取得して動的にC#の型に変換できますか？

Tags: c#

USER_TAB_COLUMNSからカラムの型(CHARやNUMBER等）を取得して、
その型を基に動的にC#の型に変換する方法はありますでしょうか？

個別に変換マップを作ってCHARならstring型にするという定義を
持つしかないでしょうか？

最終的には、OracleだけでなくSQLServer等にも対応したいと
考えております。

このあたり、何かノウハウ等ありましたらご教示ください。

Comment: この質問は前提として、どのようなテーブル構造になっているか事前に把握できないということでしょうか？

Comment: @sayuriテーブル名は、分かるため調べようと思えば分かりますが
テーブル名とカラム名より、そのカラムの型をUSER_TAB_COLUMNSから取得しています。
もっと良い方法があればそちらを採用したいです。

Comment: テーブル・カラム構造を開発時に調べる行為（調べた結果をソースコードに落とし込む）と実行時に調べる行為（調べる処理自身をソースコードに落とし込む）とでは問題領域が異なります。今回の質問はどちらを問うものか明確にしてください。

Comment: 対象のテーブルはあらかじめは決まっていなく、実行時に調べる行為となります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLの型変換に関しては各RDBMS向けのプロバイダーが実装しているため、各製品固有のビューを参照する必要はありません。基本的には単に`DbDataReader`を使って`SELECT`ステートメントを実行すればよいです。

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table1";
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        var name = reader.GetName(i);
        string sqlType = reader.GetDataTypeName(i);
        Type clrType = reader.GetFieldType(i);
    }
}
```

また`DbDataReader.GetSchemaTable()`を実行すれば空の`DataTable`を返しますので、`Columns[i].DataType`などからテーブルの構造を得ることができます。

なおADO.NETでの標準的な手法は以上のとおりですが、ORM (データセットデザイナーを含む)を使用している場合はエンティティのプロパティ型を参照してください。

Comment: まだ試せてないのですがSqlParameterのSqlDbTypeと対応するC#の型がこのやり方でわかると理解してよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 「カラム」を調べるだけであれば単純な`SELECT`で事足りるのでパラメーターは関係ないと思いますが。基本的には必要はないと思いますが、仮に何らかの理由で`DbType`やその他の列挙値にマッピングしたい場合は独自実装することになります。

Comment: またSQLパラメーターの型はSQLステートメントから一意に決められるようなものではありません。わからないのであれば指定せずに既定の変換に任せることもできます。またストアドプロシージャについては各`CommandBuilder`の`static`メソッドで名前からパラメーター情報を解決することが出来ます。

Comment: 規定の変換に任せるというのは、SqlParameterのコンストラクタで、SqlDbTypeを指定しないということですよね。独自実装は避けたいのでDbTypeへの変換もできればADO.NET側に任せたいと考えております。